# Won't return object

Tags: java, object, arraylist, iteration

```
private ArrayList players =  new ArrayList<Player>();

public Player getPlayerByName(String theName){
     for(int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++){
        String pName =  (String) players.get(i);
        if(pName.equals(theName)){
            return (Player) players.get(i);
    } else{
        return null;
    }
 }
```

Above is my code. So, the error comes from this method saying that it must return a Player type yet I am doing so after searching for the matching strings. What do you do for this to work? My apologies if this has been answered already.

Comment: if players.size == 0. that's your current issue, there is no return statement for that scenario. take that return null out of the else and for, and put it after the loop

Comment: Also note that if the code were consistently indented, the error would be clearer. If you're using an IDE, it should be able to indent your code for you.

Comment: Thank you @Stultuske! The Array is filled with info from a different file and I can see it all on the debugger. I did take out the return and that was a dumb mistake my apologies.

Comment: @JonSkeetjob so the indentation was me trying to get the code on here.... it's formatted well on the actual file I was just exuberantly tired last night and wanted to get this question up before heading to bed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues in the presemted code:

1. List `players` should contain `Player` objects, but in the loop the element of the list is cast to `String` before comparison, and then the same element is cast to `Player`.
2. Only the first element in the list is checked, if it's not matched, a `null` returned

The code should be fixed like this:

```java
private List<Player> players =  new ArrayList<>();

public Player getPlayerByName(String theName) {
    for (Player player : players) {
        String pName = player.getName();
        if (pName.equals(theName)) {
            return player;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

It may be worth to use Java Stream for this task:

```java
public Player getPlayerByName(String theName) {
    return players.stream()  // Stream<Player>
        .filter(p -> p.getName().equals(theName)) // keep matched by name
        .findFirst() // pick the first match
        .orElse(null); // provide null if no match is found
}
```

Comment: Hey Alex! Thank you so much for your help. I did try to put it in the code and run it, but the issue that I run into it the way you have written is that players in the for loop errors out stating that it cannot convert the object to Player.

Comment: I figured out what I did wrong! You are seriously awesome! My apologies!

Answer (score 1):

As your return statement is inside the for loop, you must have a return statement at the end of the function.

Because when the return statement is inside a conditional statement(or a loop), there is a possibility that the condition is false and the program may never reach the return statement.

Comment: Thanks so much! Yeah I took it out of the loop... it was a dunderhead mistake of mine!